# Is there any tool that may let me graph an antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

I tried Desmos but it only takes definite integrals (which doesn't make sense to me because a definite integral is a number not a function, but anyways). Is there anything that lets you graph an antiderivative? Say for example if I wanted to graph $\int 2x\,dx$ (and that should show me the graph of $x^2$).

Comment: wolframalpha.com . For example, [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+antiderivative+of+2*x]

Comment: Desmos works if you set the bounds from a constant to $x$ and use a different letter for the integration parameter (as in $\int_0^x f(t)dt$).

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend this tool: https://www.integral-calculator.com/.

I use this all the time for integrating: it can do definite and indefinite integrals. If you scroll down once you submit an integral to be computed there is a graph which has the integrand and the indefinite integral plotted (so for your example: the graph shows the plot of $y=2x$ and $y=x^2$). Since indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant shift, you can specify this constant shift $C$ in the graph (it is $C=0$ by default).

Comment: +1. This tool is very amazing. Thanks for sharing it!